# Calculate normal and shear stresses with fault plane dimensions, slip, orientation and regional stress tensor

Tags: geology, structural-geology

I'm trying to verify that some code I have is running correctly when calculating the Coulomb stress change. So for a example I have a fault with :

Length = 70 m,
Slip= 0.004 m,
Orientation(strike/dip/rake) = 93/71/-29

and the regional stress tensor. How do I go about calculataing the normal and shear stress for this?

Many Thanks

James